# Run a Google Script when a file is added to a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-drive-api

I would like a google script to run every time a file is added to a specific folder. Can this be done? Currently, I have a trigger that causes the script to run every minute, however this is not always fast enough.

Comment: There's not a trigger for that, if that's what you're hoping. How are things getting into the folder, and do you have any control over that?

Comment: Yes, I have control over how they are being added

Comment: Have you looked at Drive REST API, the `Changes` resource?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65902954/11225291) is a workaround solution for whoever is still watching this thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function mainFunction(){
  const folderID = 'folderID'; //provide here the ID of the folder
  const newCounter = countFiles(folderID);
  const runCode = checkProperty(folderID, newCounter);
  
  if(runCode){
   // here execute your main code
   // 
    console.log("I am executed!");
   //
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).